# Prevent line break before :

Tags: line-breaking, polyglossia, french

Here is my minimal code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\begin{document}
Bonjour tout le monde. Si je vais au bout de la ligne, je vais avoir cela : non !
\end{document}
```

Here is the result: [image]

How can I prevent the line break just before ":"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a bug in gloss-french (or more precisely it hasn't been updated to the new xetex yet). The space/boundary has in the newer xetex versions another class. This avoids the break:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\makeatletter
\XeTeXinterchartoks 4095 \french@punctthin = {\xpg@unskip\nobreak\thinspace}%
\XeTeXinterchartoks 4095 \french@punctthick = {\xpg@unskip\nobreakspace}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Bonjour tout le monde. Si je vais au bout de la ligne, je vais avoir cela : non !
\end{document}
```

A patch that would allow you to run the document with luatex too would be:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\french@punctuation{255}{4095}{}{}
\patchcmd\french@punctuation{255}{4095}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Bonjour tout le monde. Si je vais au bout de la ligne, je vais avoir cela : non !
\end{document}
```

Beside this you don't have to add the space in the input as the french module will do it for you

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\begin{document}
Bonjour tout le monde. Si je vais au bout de la ligne, je vais avoir cela: non!
\end{document}
```

(Imho if you also write in other languages it is a good idea to get used to an input without spaces as it will give the wrong output e.g. in an english or german context.)

[image]

Comment: @cjorssen: Do you mean that you have already written a lot of *source* code writing things like `cela :` instead of `cela:`?

Comment: @cjorssen: I edited the answer. Actually there is a bug in gloss-french.

Comment: Thanks. So it affects only `xetex`?

Comment: @cjorssen: Yes together with polyglossia. babel/frenchb has already adapted the code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for the edited answer, the fix works! (I think you should make the edit the main answer: in French it's really not acceptable to have no space before : in source code).

Comment: I adapted the answer. The bug has already been reported: https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/145. Besides this: Imho the french module of babel is much more sophisticated then the one of polyglossia.