# Polyglossia and French punctuation with explicit spaces

Tags: xetex, polyglossia

When I write in French, I tend to include a space before « high » punctuation:

```
Voici un point-virgule ; je mets un espace avant.
Voici une « citation » entre guillemets.
```

With Babel, the spaces are automatically made unbreakable ; with Polyglossia, I must either write an unbreakable space (`~`) or omit the space altogether.  Is it possible to automatically make the space unbreakable with Polyglossia ?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330844/prevent-line-break-before/330848#330848

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thanks, this fixes it for colons (which is a big improvement).  Any solution for the guillemets?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent line break before :](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330844/prevent-line-break-before)