# Hanging footnotes do not work in memoir with French in polyglossia

Tags: memoir, polyglossia

I use hanging footnotes style in a book typeset with the `memoir` class. To make them hang I use the following code:

```
\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{1.8em}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{0em}
\footmarkstyle{#1\hfill}
```

This works as expected as long as I don't use french with `polyglossia`: As soon as I do so, the hanging footnotes are gone:

```
\setmainlanguage[]{french}
```

Or:

```
\setotherlanguages{french}
```

The problem only occurred after the last update of `texlive` packages with came together with Ubuntu 16.10 (Version: 2016.20160819-2). It used, however, to work with the packages shipped with Ubuntu 16.4 (Version: 2015.20160320-1). Is this a bug? Or has something changed, what I am not aware of?

Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=old,babelshorthands=true,script=latin]{german}
\setotherlanguage[variant=polytonic]{greek}{}
\setotherlanguages{french}

\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{1.8em}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{0em}
\footmarkstyle{#1\hfill}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Phantastic Essay of X}
\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext} Don't waste your time reading this!\footnote{Don't waste your time reading this!}

\section{Don't waste your time reading this!}
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: In fact, you only need set the main language to `french`....

Comment: @jon But I need various languages in the book. And it works with all other languages.

Comment: No, I mean the problem can be simplified. It is about using `french` with polyglossia, not about `french` being an 'other' language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

gloss-french.ldf redefines `\@makefntext`, This is by purpose https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/12 but imho the implementation is bad as it doesn't take into account that the language is perhaps not the main language. For your language combination I wouldn't use polyglossia but babel, where the french support is much better:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[greek.polutoniko,french,german]{babel}

\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{1.8em}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{0em}
\footmarkstyle{#1\hfill}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Phantastic Essay of X}
\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext} Don't waste your time reading this!\footnote{Don't waste your time reading this!}

\section{Don't waste your time reading this!}
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Unfortunately I can't switch to babel easily, as I depend on some of its functions. I mark this as Answer anyway, because generally it would be a solution. Does anybody know how to restore the original `memoir` `\@makefntext`?

Comment: What functions? For your languages I wouldn't know of anything where polyglossia is really needed, and its french module isn't up-to-date http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330844/prevent-line-break-before/330848#330848. Beside this `\makeatletter\def\@makefntext#1{\makefootmark #1}\makeatother` should restore the older definition.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled across the same, I would call it, bug. If you do not want to switch to babel you can copy gloss-french.ldf into your directory and just comment out the concerned lines, 157-159, i.e.

```
%\ifx\@makefntext\undefined\else
%\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{\quad\ifx\@thefnmark\empty\else\@thefnmark\space\fi #1}
%\fi
```

There will be better ways to deal with this.